# Exchange 2010 (SBS 2011) not working with Win 8 & Outlook 2013

Tags: exchange-2010, windows-sbs-2011, windows-8, microsoft-office-2013

I'm unable to determine what is causing a Lenovo Tablet 2 equipped with Win 8 Pro / Office 2013 not to be able to connect to our exchange server 2010 SP2 RU4.

The weird part is that it only happens once I've joined the Tablet to the SBS domain & use any domain user.

- Using a local account = Exchange/Office 2013 getting along happily.
- Using a Domain Account with Local admin rights = Exchange/Office 2013
  being ugly.

**Event log contains the following:**

```
Faulting application name: OUTLOOK.EXE, version: 15.0.4420.1017, time stamp: 0x506734e2
Faulting module name: olmapi32.dll, version: 15.0.4420.1017, time stamp: 0x5067330a
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0006c3bf
Faulting process id: 0x1964
Faulting application start time: 0x01ce0970cba18b56
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15\OUTLOOK.EXE
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15\olmapi32.dll
Report Id: 0b49592e-7564-11e2-afa9-6894239576ac
Faulting package full name:
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

After reinstalls/repairs/renames of the dll I haven't been able to get to work.

**Anybody else ran into this?**

Comment: Same Problem here. Usually Outlook works, but sometimes I have the exact same crash relating to Olmapi32.dll - also socialconnector.dll.

Answer (score 1):

IN the end I determined that the cause was due to an old/unused feature the previous admin had used. I simply removed this.

%logonserver%\netlogon\Default User.v2

Users now have access to exchange via outlook 2013 with now issue.

http://patrick.eviltools.com/default-domain-profile/